# Remove amp from url .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to remove amp from url. htaccess

special characters create duplicate content

example

/b-amp-b.html

/b-b.html

how can I do?
I have a problem in the url rewriting, two pages are created equal a / b-amp-b.html the other /b-b.html that's why i want to remove amp

Comment: can you clarify what does "special characters create duplicate content" mean exactly? and why is this tagged with php?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean the `&` character and not the word "amp", you'd do something like this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(.*)[&%\^@](.*)$ /$1$2
```

The `[&%\^@]` is where you'd fill in with all the "special" characters that you don't want

Comment: I have a problem in the url rewriting, two pages are created equal a / b-amp-b.html the other /b-b.html that's why i want to remove amp